# View page does not reload when modelstate fails

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I am using jquery ajax to post data to action. When model state is valid then jquery ajax shows perfect result. But when model state is not valid, It does not return anything and does not reload my view page in mvc.

My Action method code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AllLandLord(User_Master usermaster, CityDate citydate)
    {
        List<User_Master> allLandLord = new List<User_Master>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            allLandLord = agreementnewBAL.AllLandLordUsers();
            return PartialView("LoadLandLord", allLandLord);
        }
        else
        {
            int successid= 1;


            return Json(new { id = successid});
        }
    }
}
```

In my View, Jquery code as follws

```
  var usermodel = {
            US_FirstName:$("#txtFirstName").val(),
            US_LastName:$("#txtLastName").val(),
            US_Gender:$(".userGender").filter(':checked').val(),
            US_Age:$("#txtAge").val(),
            US_Email:$("#txtEmail").val(),
            US_MobileNo:$("#txtMobile").val(),
            US_PAN:$("#txtPan").val(),
            US_AadharNo:$("#txtAadhar").val(),
            US_PermanentAddress:$("#txtPermanentAddress").val()
        };
        var citydatemodel = {
            CM_AgreementSignDate:$("#SignDate").val(),
            PR_City: $("#selectCity").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("AllLandLord")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({usermaster: usermodel, citydate: citydatemodel}),
                    type:'POST',
                    UpdateTargetId: "dvLandLord3",
                    success:function(data){

                        if(data.id== 1)
                        {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#dvLandLord3").html(data);
                        }

                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('something went wrong!');
                    }
                });
```

I checked it using debugger, But it doesn't work for me. So, how can I reload my view page when model state valid is false?

Comment: What are you really trying to do here. If `data.successid` is `1` then you just reload the page. What is the point of using ajax in this case? And `UpdateTargetId` is not an option of the ajax function.

Comment: If `data.successid` is `1` then I want to reload my parent view(current page), But it's not going to reload my view.

Comment: Using ajax is pointless in this case, but your controller never sends a value for `successid ` (although it does send a value for a property named `id`)

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: I have edited my code, Please see it again.

Comment: Your still sending back an json object with a property named `id` (not `successid`) - `return Json(new { successid= 1});`

Comment: And the fact that your manually generating your object to post instead of using `data: $('form').serialize()` suggests you don't know how to generate your view correctly either.

Comment: Again I have edited my code, This time it's also not working.  I am not using `$('form').serialize()` , Because I am using Another action rather than current form action

Comment: That has nothing to do with it (the url is specified using `url: '@Url.Action("AllLandLord")',`, not the action in the form).

Comment: What happens when I manually generates my objects to post?

Comment: Your just writing a whole lot of unnecessary code :) But using ajax to post data and then calling `location.reload();` just makes no sense so I can't even understand what the purpose of this is.

Comment: So, how do I call `location.reload();` when my `model.isvalid` false ?

Comment: What do you think that would do if `ModelState` was invalid? - it would just refresh everything and you would loose all the data the user has entered and no error messages would ever be displayed.

Comment: Actually I want to display error messages, Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: Then your going about this all wrong. Need some sleep now, but I suggest you do some research and if necessary, ask a new question with a clearer explanation of what your wanting to do - i.e. display error messages (instead of just posting code which does not make sense). Although its unclear why you are not just doing a normal submit in this case.